Car Warriors in a Junkyard
My friend and I were talking about this show the other day. It aired weekdays at 6 or 6:30 AM. Some or all of these details may be wrong, but it had a group of people (potentially Mighty Morphin' Power Ranger age) who lived/worked in a junkyard, and they transformed into or rode around in these Transformer-esque cars. The whole thing was filled with bad '90s CGI. They fought bad guys, and in one episode, a villain tries to marry the girl of the group.
Very sketchy info, but if anyone can identify this show, I'd love to know!

Sounds like you're after 90s kids show Van-Pires (seriously), which was one of the first shows to incorporate a large amount of CGI with live action and is about about teens hanging out in a junkyard who can turn into cars:

The Van-Pires [...] stories center on a group of human teenagers who protect and defend the world from evil anthropomorphized junkyard vans and vehicles known as the "Van-Pires" by transforming into robotic anthropomorphized cars, calling themselves the "Motor-Vators".

Here's a clip:




Even by kids-show standards, that's some truly awful acting.
